# Python sorting by three criteria

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm trying to get a handle on sorting by several criteria (length, suffix and alphabetically in that order). I can't quite get a grip on it though, and all I seem to be able to do is sort by length...

Here's my code (python 2.7.9):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

sortme = [
    'one.ab',
    'two.ef',
    'three.ab',
    'six.ef',
    'seven.jk',
    'eight.ef',
    'nine.xy',
    'five.xy',
    'ten.ab',
    'Four.ef'
]

sortme.sort(key=lambda item: (-len(item), item), reverse=True)

print(sortme)
```

This gets the length part, but I'm really trying to get:

```
(ab)
one.ab
ten.ab
three.ab

(ef)
six.ef
two.ef
four.ef
eight.ef

(jk)
seven.jk

(xy)
five.xy
nine.xy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify multiple sort keys as a tuple:

```
sortme.sort(key=lambda item: (item.split('.')[1], len(item), item), reverse=False)

print("\n".join(sortme))
```

Output:

```
one.ab
ten.ab
three.ab
six.ef
two.ef
Four.ef
eight.ef
seven.jk
five.xy
nine.xy
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks! Is it difficult to group the suffixes or separate them at all?

Comment: You could look into a dictionary and the setdefault method. Something like `d.setdefault(suffix, []).append(item)`

Answer (score 0):

```
sortme.sort(key=lambda item: (-len(item),item.rsplit(".",1)[-1], item), reverse=True)
```

you just add your 3rd criteria ... I would really recommend sitting down with a tutor or your teacher.

you can always break it off into its own funtion to make it more understandable

```
def sort_key(item):
    return -len(item),item.rsplit(".",1)[-1],item

sortme.sort(key=sort_key,reverse=True)
```

Comment: For whatever reason this yields 'None' each time I try it, thanks.

Comment: `a.sort` sorts the array in place and returns none, the actual array is changed ... use `sorted(sortme,key=sort_key,reverse=True)` if you want to return a new sorted array

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `cmp` function:

```
import re


sortme = [
    'one.ab',
    'two.ef',
    'three.ab',
    'six.ef',
    'seven.jk',
    'eight.ef',
    'nine.xy',
    'five.xy',
    'ten.ab',
    'Four.ef'
]

def _cmp(first, second):
    first_type = first.split('.')[-1]
    second_type = second.split('.')[-1]
    if first_type == second_type:
        return cmp(len(first), len(second))

    return cmp(first_type, second_type)

sortme.sort(cmp=_cmp)

print(sortme)
```

Comment: This puts "five.xy" after "nine.xy", so something is a bit off it seems, thanks.